# 'sort3'was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

How can I correct my code? I don't understand the meaning of `sort3 was not declared in this scope`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ( )
{
   cout<<" Enter first value. "<<endl;
   int a;
   cin>> a;

   cout<<"Enter second value. "<<endl;
   int b;
   cin>>b;

   cout<<"Enter third value. "<<endl;
   int c;
   cin>>c;

   sort3(a,b,c);
   cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
   return 0;
}

void sort3(int& a, int& b, int&c )
{
    int temp;

    if (a < b )
    {
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    else if (a < c )
    {
        temp = a;
        a = c;
        c = temp;
    }
    else if ( b < c )
    {
        temp = b;
        b = c;
        c = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forward declaration... The compiler doesn't trust you that you didn't do any mistakes (function name, parameters.. etc..) So he should first see the declaration to believe you..

Answer (score 3):

You can "declare" the `sort3` function before main:

```
void sort3(int& a, int& b, int&c );

int main ()
{
...
```

The other option would be to move the definition of `sort3` before main.

In C++, you need at least a declaration of a function before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the declaration before the first time to use the function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sort3(int& a, int& b, int&c );    //declaration

int main ( )
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare

```
void sort3(int&, int&, int& );
```

Before `main` function it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Either put the declaration before the function:

```
void sort3(int& a, int& b, int&c )
int main()
```

or try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sort3(int& a, int& b, int&c )
{
  int temp;

  if (a < b )
  {
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }
  else if (a < c )
  {
    temp = a;
    a = c;
    c = temp;
  }
  else if ( b < c )
  {
    temp = b;
    b = c;
    c = temp;
  }
}
int main ( )
{


 cout<<" Enter first value. "<<endl;
 int a;
 cin>> a;

 cout<<"Enter second value. "<<endl;
 int b;
 cin>>b;

 cout<<"Enter third value. "<<endl;
 int c;
 cin>>c;



 sort3(a,b,c);
 cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Note that the declaration of the function must be before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the compiler parses your file from top to bottom. So the compiler comes across your call to `sort3` but it has never been declared.

To solve this problem, you can use a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) or move the whole `sort3`-function in front of your `main()`.

The Solution with forward declaration:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sort3(int& a, int& b, int&c );

int main ( )
{
   ... code ...
}

void sort3(int& a, int& b, int&c )
{
    ... code ...
}
```

Without forward declaration, but `sort3` moved in front of `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sort3(int& a, int& b, int&c )
{
    ... code ...
}

int main ( )
{
   ... code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sort3(int& a, int& b, int&c )
{
    int temp;

    if (a < b )
    {
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    else if (a < c )
    {
        temp = a;
        a = c;
        c = temp;
    }
    else if ( b < c )
    {
        temp = b;
        b = c;
        c = temp;
    }
}
int main ( )
{


   cout<<" Enter first value. "<<endl;
   int a;
   cin>> a;

   cout<<"Enter second value. "<<endl;
   int b;
   cin>>b;

   cout<<"Enter third value. "<<endl;
   int c;
   cin>>c;



  sort3(a,b,c);
   cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

or you can define the function in the top, after the line 'using namespace std;`

```
void sort3(int &, int &, int &);
```